# From which kind of bird is this feather?

Tags: birds, bird-identification, feathers

Found this in our yard.
Curious of what type bird it may be from. We live in Tulsa, Oklahoma.
[image: feather]

Comment: Can you give a measurement of the length of the feather? It will likely help with identification

Comment: Welcome to the Outdoors Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Can you please edit into your question how long the feather is - I'm guessing about 10 cm/5 in long as that looks like a tissue (kleenex for you USAians) in the background.

Comment: Perhaps it's a [chicken feather](https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/ginger-rooster-feather-on-white-gm154246290-19159220). It's in poor condition so the bird might have been pecked a lot and not flown much.

Comment: Its exactly 6 inches long!